# How to run scala project with sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, blockchain

I'm trying to run a private waves blockchain network on windows 10.

After following some of waves docs instructions (`sbt "test:runMain tools.GenesisBlockGenerator src/test/resources/genesis.example.conf"`)

These errors comes up. what's the matter?

[image]

Update:

It starts with this error `java.io.IOException: CreateFile() failed with error 123`.

Comment: looks like either of 2 issues. internet connection in your system or you might be using removed artifact from the repository.

Comment: [Check first Mircrosoft site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/installer-wrappercreatefile-failed-with-error-123/3b180316-95c2-4613-8c38-8515481db22c) - Are you use not standard charackters in path? Comment from site: `In my case the letters were Greek! `

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik yeah exactly. after I run the command some files with non-standard characters appear in the path.

Comment: I also checked microsoft forum. didn't work either.

Comment: The answer is in last post (from DebsBoletis). There are a 6 hidden Replies.

Comment: @AndrzejJozwik my username is all en. guess this solution won't work too